# Search a list of keywords in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0, couchdb-mango

I have documents containing lists of keywords. How can I query such that a search for e.g., the keywords `bela` and `fleck` returns only documents that have both of those keywords:

```
{
    "_id": "track/bela-fleck/big-country",
    "title": "Big Country",
    "artist": "Bela Fleck",
    "keywords": ["bela", "fleck", "big", "country"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a Mango query. First, create an index on the `keywords` field:

```
{
   "index": {
      "fields": [
         "keywords"
      ]
   },
   "name": "keywords-index",
   "type": "json"
}
```

Then, query using `$elemMatch` to find items in the array matching each keyword, and `$and` to find documents that match all keywords:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "keywords": {
         "$and": [
            {
               "$elemMatch": {
                  "$eq": "bela"
               }
            },
            {
               "$elemMatch": {
                  "$eq": "fleck"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Note that this method [does not use indexes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2867) to search inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
function map(doc) {
  // sort by each keyword
  for (var k in doc.keywords) {
    emit(doc.keywords[k], null);
  }      
}

db.query(map).then(function (result) {
  // handle result
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

...but I have not tested it! Also this does a full database scan, so for efficiency you should create a view in design doc as described in the [PouchDb API documentation for Map/Reduce](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database). Hope this helps.

Update... [the CouchDb guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html) also has some detailed examples that may help.

Comment: I don't think it will work with CouchDB 2.X as temporary view are not supported. The suggested way would be to define a view in a design document with the same mapping function.